# Passing dictionary between view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management, properties

I'm missing something fundamental here.

I have a table view with each cell displaying the contents of an NSDictionary. When I tap on each cell I would like to segue to a new view controller displaying details from the same dictionary.

But every time i try pass the dictionary it's contents are null on the other side.

Here's my prepare for segue in the view controller containing the table view:

```
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue*)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"tableSegue"]){

        MODetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MODetailViewController alloc] init];

        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.monetiseTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
        int selectedIndexPathAsInteger = selectedIndexPath.row;

        NSDictionary *dictionaryToPass = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.feedArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndexPathAsInteger]];

        NSLog(@"%@", dictionaryToPass);

        detailViewController.passedDictionary = dictionaryToPass;
    }
}
```

The NSLog displays the dictionary as expected.

Now, in detail view controller header I have declared the property (i'm using ARC):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDictionary *passedDictionary;
```

Now in viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

NSLog(@"%@", self.passedDictionary);
}
```

The NSLog is returning null!?

I have synthesised it.

I'm missing something fundamental i'm sure. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDictionary *passedDictionary;
```

instead of `weak`, declare it `strong`.

This will prevent the dictionary from being dealloc'ed.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks. It's about time I had a real read over retain, copy, assign, weak, strong etc!

Comment: if declared passedDictionary as strong, sometimes detailviewcontroller is not getting deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't allocate a new MODetailViewController.  Use the one that's passed to you as the destination controller in the segue parameter.